# How to run only failed specs in protractor on re-run option

Tags: protractor, specs

I am looking for a package that will re-run only failed specs. Which package is better, 
I saw that protractor-retry and protractor flake are two options, because flake works on all specs on each attempt that will not suit me.

Looking something like run 10 specs in suite->5 failed (each describe is one spec, because I am using data provider)

In 2nd attempt, pick only those 5 specs and re-run -> 2 failed,
In 3rd attempt, pick those 2 and re-run.

Though Protractor-retry does this all, I see pull-req are only 2 and downloads are very less, how's the support of this? Can I go with this package?

Comment: Any one has some clues on this?